# Pointing two urls long and short for the same website

Tags: seo, domains, url

As `facebook.com` this is the long url and the short one for facebook is `fb.com` so if I have a website with a keyword like database for example `englishdatabase.com` and I want to make it shorter like `englishdb.com` so does it affects my rank in google as duplicate content ? which one should I consider as the main website and redirects the other one to ?

Comment: Two domains do nothing but spend your money twice as fast. Forget the shorter domain name. It does nothing for you.

Comment: @closetnoc is right. Use longer one because it has your keywords. BTW why do you want to shorten your domain name?

Answer (score 1):

> Does [this] affects my rank[ing] in [G]oogle [regarding] duplicate content?

[Google has this to say:](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content within or across domains that either completely match other content or are appreciably similar. Mostly, this is not deceptive in origin. Examples of non-malicious duplicate content could include:
>
> - Discussion forums that can generate both regular and stripped-down pages targeted at mobile devices
> - Store items shown or linked via multiple distinct URLs
> - Printer-only versions of web pages
>
> [...]
>
> **Duplicate content on a site is not grounds for action on that site unless it appears that the intent of the duplicate content is to be deceptive and manipulate search engine results.**

*Regarding redirection specifically*, I would choose the shortened URL for the main site but you should know that englishdatabase.com could be considered in search results. A search engine may know "facebook" is a site called facebook.com but what is "fb"?

However, if you were able to register "englishdb.com", I would likely think this would be sufficient. It's short and snappy and despite the less than perfect "db", any shortcomings could likely be overcome by using the phrase "english database" strategically in accordance with good SEO practices.

Regarding duplicate content issues, you may find that even if you follow [some canonization guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066), Google holding duplicate content against you may not be the real issue. **The real issue with multiple URLs may be that you have difficulty stopping Google or other search engines from indexing your site in a way you would not prefer.** Every URL pointing to a piece of content is a potential gateway to that content and a search engine will likely at least consider listing each one.

[In this Webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86163/redirecting-https-to-http/86200#86200), note that Wordpress was being used, which is a CMS that offers two links to each post. Thus, the original poster had a total of 8 address (including http:// and https://) that could potentially be listed in Google *for each post*. This seems like a recipe for a headache.

As a final note, often the reason to have a second URL is for purposes of separation. For instance, gmail.com for google.com and ymail.com for yahoo.com are aimed squarely at the mobile market since they are easier to type. Likewise, if a large organization needs to separate domains for ease of data retrieval, that is another common use. So having "englishdb.com" connect to "englishdatabase.com" to retrieve, say, english data, might make sense, but using it just to hold a second copy of "englishdb.com" seems counter-productive.

Comment: The only thing I see you forgetting is the semantic value of englishdatabase.com is essentially cut in half with englishdb.com. This is an important semantics signal. The longer domain name has more value. While db can semantically equate to database, it is not wise to count on it. As well, englishdatabase.com has established some level of trust rank and englishdb.com would not possess any rank at all. Short of that, this is an outstanding answer! One up-vote!!